# Add BE user with password in TYPO3 CMS extension

Tags: php, security, typo3, extbase

I've created successfully a BE user in an own extension for TYPO3 CMS 8.7.0.

Repository Injection:

```
/**
 * beUserRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $beUserRepository = null;
```

Part of the ActionController:

```
$beuser = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser();
$beuser->setUserName($username);
$beuser->setEmail($email);
$beuser->setRealName($realname);
$this->beUserRepository->add($beuser);
```

This works fine but I can't add a password like for FE users with `setPassword()`. Is there any way to get there or is it restricted for security reasons to set/change a BE user password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own BackendUser model in your extension

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Model;

class BackendUser extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password = '';

    /**
     * Returns the password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = (string)$password;
    }
}
```

Create your own Repository

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Repository;

class BackendUserRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository
{
}
```

Then map your new domain model to be_users table:

```
plugin.tx_yourExtKey {
    persistence {
        classes {
            YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Model\BackendUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = be_users
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update your controller to use your new Repository

```
/**
 * beUserRepository
 *
 * @var \YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $beUserRepository;
```

Back in your action

```
$beUser = new \YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Model\BackendUser();
$saltFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance('', 'BE');
$beUser->setPassword($saltFactory->getHashedPassword($newPassword));
```

Comment: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser::setPassword() - Can you add the line with your `$user` definition?!

Comment: Hello Pete. That's another story. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser` does not have a password property, so you can not set a password without extending the model. The easiest way would be if you create an own `BackendUser` model in your extension that extends the `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser` and configure the mapping in TS. It just needs to have the `$password` property with getters/setters and a repository.

Comment: You're right in case of TYPO3 datahandler, but extbase has its own persistance. Please do a recursive search through extbase with word "password", you will only find some setters, but there is no result in DataMapper for password. So, hashing will not be done automatically in extbase context.

Comment: You are right about the hashing. I must have mistaken it with the old pre 4.5 TCA configuration of eval=md5, where it was not needed anymore for the backend